# Wrapper or proxy for INavigationService

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Does it possible to provide a custom implementation for `INavigationService` in `Xamarin.Forms` `Prism` app?

Comment: Sure, why not? What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: I don't know the correct way of doing it. I've tried `containerRegistry.Register<INavigationService, MyImpl>();` but it didn't work.

Comment: @Anatoly Are there any update for this issue? If Haukinger's answer is helpful, please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried `containerRegistry.Register<INavigationService, MyImpl>();`

This registers `MyImpl` transiently, so each time it is resolved, you get a new instance. Unless `MyImpl` instance somehow communicate with each other, this won't work as expected.

Normally, one wants a singleton in this case, so that only a single instance is ever resolved:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<INavigationService, MyImpl>();
```